# Google calendar API - Appointment schedule

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

In Google calendar you can add "Appointment schedule"
[image]

These are events that repeat periodically. But they are not created from ordinary events. They are created precisely by the schedule.

How can I access them using Google API?

I have tried `service.events().list` and `service.events().instances` and neither appear to return it.

I'm using python
Here is my code using service.events().instances

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

import datetime
import time
import schedule

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

load_dotenv()

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]


def main():
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists("token.json"):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(
            "token.json", SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                "credentials.json", SCOPES
            )
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open("token.json", "w") as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build("calendar", "v3", credentials=creds)
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'  
        week_later = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() +
                  datetime.timedelta(days=7)).isoformat() + 'Z'
        # Call the Calendar API
        instances_result = (
            service.events()
            .instances(
                calendarId="primary",
                timeMin=now,
                timeMax=week_later,
                maxResults=100,
                eventId='recurringEventId',
            )
            .execute()
        )
        instances = instances_result.get("items", [])
        if not instances:
            print("No upcoming instances found.")
            return

        # Prints the start and name of the next 10 events
        for instance in instances:
            start = instance["start"].get(
                "dateTime", instance["start"].get("date"))
            print(start, instance["summary"])
    

    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

After running the program I get "No upcoming instances found."

Comment: Check this [recurring_events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/events-calendars#recurring_events) If that doesn't help edit your question include a [example] and I will have a look.   Just add a comment here once you have added your code and i will get a notification.

Comment: Suddenly, these events appeared along with the usual ones and now they can be received using the code - https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python

Only the name of the event cannot be obtained, everyone has the same name - Recurring event